# Win32: How can I detect when a computer is added or removed from network in real time?

Tags: winapi, wnet

Using the various `WNet` functions you can get a list of computers for given workgroups or domains.   How can I detect, in real-time, when a computer shuts down (removed from network) or a new one starts up (added to network) without having to consistently scan?  I thought I recall coming across a notification type message for network devices, but I can't find it now or may have been for something else.

Thanks.

Comment: possible you can use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/nla/portal